# my script working on my localhost while not working on internet hosting

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

I got this warning on the web hosting, on page (report-hours-male.php) as following

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/hatimmak/public_html/ssp12/report-hours-male.php on line 28
```

my problem is:
The script is working fine on my localhost >> on my computer
while not working on internet hosting !!!!!

this is the page

```
    <?php


include 'config.php';

?><BR>

Report for year <?php echo $_SESSION['year']; ?>  semester <?php echo $_SESSION['sem']; ?>  

<?php
 // list of teachers Table rows and total hours

echo "<table border='0' id='hor-minimalist-b' >
<tr>
<th scope='col'>Instructor name</th>
<th scope='col'>Total hours for this semester</th>
</tr>"; 


        //$gender = $_SESSION['gender'];
        $year = $_SESSION['year'];
        $sem = $_SESSION['sem'];

        $tab = "Report$year$sem";
        $query = "SELECT teacher, SUM(hours) FROM $tab GROUP BY teacher"; 
        $result = mysql_query($query) ;



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{


        $time = gmdate(DATE_RFC822);

        //$gender = $_SESSION['gender'];
        $year = $_SESSION['year'];
        $sem = $_SESSION['sem'];
        //$teacher = $_row['teacher'];
        //$sumhours = $_row['SUM(hours)'];



echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> ". $row['teacher']." </td>";
echo "<td> ". $row['SUM(hours)']." </td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>

<!--chart-->
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'hours');
        data.addRows([

<?php


        $queryr = "SELECT teacher, SUM(hours) FROM $tab GROUP BY teacher"; 
        $resultr = mysql_query($queryr) ;

while($rowr = mysql_fetch_array($resultr))
{
        $teacherr = $_rowr['teacher'];
        $sumhoursr = $_rowr['SUM(hours)'];


echo "['".$rowr['teacher']."' , ".$rowr['SUM(hours)']."]," ;
}

?>
          ['', 0]


        ]);

        // Set chart options

        var options = {'title':'Contact hours/instructor',
                'legend':'left',
                'is3D':true,

                'width':800,
                'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <center><div id="chart_div"></div></center>

   <form>
<input type="button" value="Print This Report" onclick="window.print();">  </form>

  </body>
</html>

<?php

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

this is th config.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","hatimmak_ssp","userpass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$sel = mysql_select_db("hatimmak_ssp", $con) or die();

?>
```

help me please :(

Comment: Your database connection probably hasn't been made successfully.

Comment: change the $result variable with ``$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());`` then write it here to see what kind of problem it is.

Comment: in your questions, include just all the relevant code. This would mean in this case the database connection and the code from the db connection to where the error appears.

Comment: Check php-mysql version at host end and yours

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suspect is the values of any of these: $tab, teacher, hours.
they need to match exactly on your host.

```
    $tab = "Report$year$sem";
    $query = "SELECT teacher, SUM(hours) FROM $tab GROUP BY teacher";
```

Comment: Thank You, Solved, the problem was on $tab = "Report$year$sem";
it should be $tab = "report$year$sem";
only R >> r

many thanks for you Mr.adydy :)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the query succeeded? You should check for errors:

```
if (mysql_query($sql))
{
    // your code
}
else 
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: This is not made obvious in your code. As Carlos mentioned it, you should only include the relevant code and also the code from where the db connection is made. If this code works fine on your test system and your DB is the same on both test and prod systems, it means the only problem I could think of is a MySQL connection problem.

Comment: i changed the $result as Gokhan Ozturk said and i got this problem,  Report for year semester Error: Table 'hatimmak_ssp.Report' doesn't exist

Comment: Do you have the same DB on both test and prod systems?

Comment: Do you have any `$_SESSION` data present at all? Try `var_dump($_SESSION);` and see what's in there